# SQL Server 2008 search

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to search inside a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Do you mean text search within the procedure definition ?

Comment: Search how? Search for what?? You need to be a bit more specific!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the searching for specific key in definiton of a stored procedure use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES** along with **OBJECT_DEFINITION** function.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION( OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME)) LIKE '%<YOUR_KEY>%'
```